# How To Test Multiplayer Games Unity Without Build The App?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

What is the best way to test a multiplayer network game in unity without build the app ?

It is something like in editor unity there is two editor which one is a copied editor. So we can login in one editor and login in second editor with different user. Is there a tool like this ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: Why is this closed?? This is not asking for recommandations for software, this is a straightforward question that can be answered with facts and citations. Shame on whoever closed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a tool like this ?

As far as i know, there is not.

> What is the best way to test a multiplayer network game in unity
>   without build the app ?

When i test, I usually build the game, and then run another instance in the editor, on separate monitors. That should work like normal.

But you need one build. :/

**If you are using the built in Unity Networking**

- Host from the editor
- Connect the build as a client

Many issues can be resolved just by changing the host, and in these cases you *don't* have to rebuild.

That being said, don't forget to rebuild every now and again to be safe. And remember, sometimes you change things that you don't realize affect the client.

Comment: Hi @OscarLundberg Thanks for sharing, but with like this, it take much time especially for waiting the game to build. What about if there is just single error in multiplayer network i must build it again to test.

Comment: Note that running on the same machine will bring its load of surprise. The same code will work just fine while running editor and instance of app on the same machine but then when running on different devices, here comes the pain. Most likely, you will hit authority issue as I did. I guess it comes from the Ip address being the same and the server just consider everyone to be server or else. In the end, I was able to alter objects with no issue. Once using different device, bam, no authority warning and errors.

Comment: @DennisLiu I know, it's rough but there is no alternative unfortunately. If you are using the built in unity networking, I'd advice you to run the build as a client, and host from the editor. That way, you may not have to build as much since many problems can be fixed just by changing the host. But yes, you will have to build the game many times. 
To clarify: If you don't change anything on the client side you don't have to rebuild.

Comment: Hi @OscarLundberg Thanks for the sharing, it look like it have no choice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ParallelSync for anything Unity 2018+, it's basically the closest successor to uecho. You can add it as a package in Unity and it will copy your project to a new folder and run however many instances you require.

https://github.com/VeriorPies/ParrelSync

Comment: why isn't this marked as accepted answer?